# Does &#8679; have a down equivalent?

Tags: html, html-encode

Does `&#8679;` (⇧) have a down equivalent? I need a chunky down arrow.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28symbol%29#Arrows_in_Unicode

Comment: http://entity-lookup.leftlogic.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - yes. `&#8681;` produces a "chunky" down arrow - ⇩.

Comment: This skinny guy does the job and is the next best thing, thanks. I had my heart set on something as fat as &#8679; but doesn't seem there is one.

Answer (score 1):

`&#8681;` will produce this: ⇩

Also of interest `&#8680;` = ⇨, and `&#8678;` = ⇦

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sure. `&#8681;` produces a nice down arrow.

> ⇩